# Sharepoint with mirrored database

Tags: installation, sql, mirroring

i'm tryin to build a lab farm where a sharepoint 2013 server will use a mirrored database. I read lots of stuff but i'm still not sure about the correct installation path.
I would roughly proceed the following way:

- Install SQL principal instance
- Install SQL mirror instance
- Install SQL witness instance
  (still no sql mirroring configuration done at this point)
- Install SP pointing to the principal server as it was the only existing db
  (better create a sql alias first pointing to the principal and install SP  using the alias?)
- Copy all the system and sp databases to mirror and setup all the mirroring thing
- Configure failover instance on Sharepoint

Does it make sense? do i forget something ?
any help will be greatly appreciated!

RL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Aliases are used for mobility. With mirroring (deprecated) or AlwaysOn Availability Groups (strongly preferred), there's no reason to use SQL Aliases as you already have that mobility in play.

But your steps sound correct.

Comment: thanks Trevor. I'm trying to setup mirroring since i dont have any shared storage available. 

I'll set mirror server as failover instance.

By the way, i'm asking you another question, cause what i found around leaves me unsure. What is the correct way to rollback from failover instance to primary? Does SP provides an automated way to do it?

Comment: You do it SQL-side. There's nothing to do on the SharePoint side (though it may take a minute or two to recognize the new primary).